# Poor performance with docker internal DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, docker

I have a problem with docker internal DNS. On one of docker container dns server is so slow that it time out most of the queries.
Docker is installed in KVM virtual machine and I have several containers spawned with docker-compose. Default docker configuration.
Querying external DNS works ok, but after some time (minutes, sometimes hours) after container startup 'ping google.com' sometimes works blazing fast and sometimes returns with host not found error (even just after previous successful run). Or it takes many seconds to find the IP of a domain.

I moved the VM to another server, changed network card configuration, even changed its OS (Debian -> Ubuntu), but it didn't solve my problem.

Only one container is affected (probably the one with the biggest number of DNS queries).

What else should I do? How to debug the problem?

Comment: Give us more information as docker version, cat /etc/resolv.conf and execution time of the command dig. For example:"time dig google.com +short"

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9, nameserver inside containers: 127.0.0.11,  time dig google.com (from few runs): 0m8.939s, 0m2.332s, 0m1.157s, 0m3.775s.

Comment: I see I have many udp checksum errors when querying DNS: `[bad udp cksum 0xaa2d -> 0x7535!] 2326 NXDomain q: A?`

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same symptoms with Docker 19.03.12 and docker-compose 1.27.3.  I must use `--internal` on network due to security risks.  Here is output from `time getent hosts rabbitmq` 
10.10.12.49     rabbitmq

real    0m10.018s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.000s

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the symptoms.  The fix for me was two things.

1. Upgrade Docker Engine from 19.x to 20.10.3.  After upgrading to this version my `celery` container was able to connect to other containers on the same internal network.  But, it could not connect to external servers like google.com for example.
2. Added an open port to my problematic container, so in `docker-compose.yaml` I added the following to my `celery` container (aka service):

```yaml
ports:
    - "65123:65123"
```

After adding this seemingly uneeded port to my `celery` container it can now connect to external servers.

**Thoughts**

I understand this is a hacky workaround, but in my case it works and seems more secure to open a port where nothing is listening than to make the entire network external.  I would value any ideas on how secure this workaround might or might not be.